# Practically making interrupted underlines that don't clash with descenders

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, typography, illustrator-effects, object-styles

I'm looking for a practical way to achieve *pretty underlining* (interrupted at descenders) in InDesign or Illustrator.

See [Should underline clash with text descenders?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/should-underline-clash-with-text-descenders)

I've tried to fake it by **applying a white stroke** to the text, but the way that cuts into the underline is too ugly to use. Because I'm trying to use it for large text with a thick underline that's also round-capped.

[image: Underline descender-guard fail - white stroke method]

Simply **removing the underline** does interrupt nicely around letter like **g**, but leaves too much of a gap for **p**

[image: Underline descender-guard fail - manual method]

If this can be achieved at all, it's got to be something only one of you wizards could think up.

It really needs to be an InDesign & Illustrator feature though (here's the [link to Adobe's *wishform*](http://www.adobe.com/products/wishform.html)). <s>Like `text-decoration-skip: ink;` from CSS3 needs browser support.</s> **March 2018:** Wow not only did it get support, it's now the default in Chrome/Chromium.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the source text you can remove the underline from characters with descenders and use spaces to make up the missing underline where needed. If you only have a handful of places where you need to do this then you can do it manually pretty easily, for anything longer you can (in InDesign) set GREP styles and use some GREP find & replace queries to do the hard work for you.

### Manually

1. Underline your text.
2. Add spaces after the "p"s.
3. Remove underline from characters with descenders.
4. Kern the "p"+"space" negatively to bring the underline under the "p"s.

[image]

### Semi-automated (InDesign only)

1. First add the underline to your paragraph style and create a character style with no underline for your descender characters.
2. Add spaces after you "p"s. You can use a GREP find & replace to find only "p"s that don't already have a space after them (so you can reuse the query on the same text if your text changes) using something like:

   [image]
3. Duplicate your no-underline character style for the "p"s. Set up some GREP styles within your paragraph style to apply the correct character styles:

   [image]
4. Now you can add some negative tracking on your "p"s to pull in the spaces (and the extra underline) to fill the gap under the "p"s.

[image]

You could expand this to a number of character styles and saved GREP find & replace queries, for example adding a space *before* a "y" and tracking the space to pull the "y" in. Once you have your styles and find & replace queries set up all you need to do is rerun the queries every time your text changes.

There are no GREP styles in Illustrator so you would have to do this manually there but this should work as a semi-automated solution in InDesign (although it is a bit "hacky").

Note also, I'm using CS6 so I'm not sure if there's anything new in CC that makes this easier.

Comment: Note an interesting (mildly infuriating) edge case for the **manual method:** if the last letter is **y**, negatively kerning spaces will do nothing to bring the underline near the descender. Only adding another letter works. I'd add a transparent one, but these are chapter headers, which populate the Table of Contents! Grrr...

Comment: Another issue: I can't use a continuous text-length gradient on an underline because whenever I interrupt it the next bit starts the gradient over.

Comment: Yeh there's going to be some edge cases that aren't as easy to work around. Another thing you can do is use a non-invisible character and set it's color to the same color as the paper (which is even more hacky, but hey).

Comment: No idea about the gradient though, not sure there's a way around that (I'm pretty sure all the underline gradient stuff is new in CC but I'm not sure)